# What is the difference between "transporte" and "trasporte"?

Tags: vocabulario

I see [RAE](https://dle.rae.es/transporte#FbKz1gv) refer to "transporte" and "trasporte". Is there a difference between them or cases when I might use one over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As RAE indicates [in the DPD](https://www.rae.es/dpd/tras-), the prefix *trans-*, meaning "behind", "on the other side", "through" is often pronounced *tras-* in common speech. Therefore, RAE accepts both forms of the prefix, so both "transporte" and "trasporte" are correct, with **no difference in meaning whatsoever**. In writing, "transporte" is the  most commonly seen version, and some people may incorrectly think that there is a mistake when they read "trasporte".

Answer (score 3):

No difference - they are two different ways to spell the same word.